# Excel Not Executing VBA For Loop Script On Excell Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has add-in functions that compute on data given in a fixed range. All the worksheets work properly with pressing of F9 or Shift-F9 keys.

I am writing a for loop with VBA. It copies a range from one worksheet which contains all the data to another worksheet. Then calculates manually one worksheet at a time, with pauses, and even compute twice so as to ensure the execution of each worksheet. If I manually step through the VBA code line by line in the debug mode through the whole for loops, everything works. However, if I press F5 and run the whole VBA for loop at full speed. The code produces the same result for many (not all) of the consecutive iterations of the for loop, while I know the results should all be different. My guess is that the workseets become stale and are not replaced with new data.

The following is my VBA code. I would really appreciate if someone would take a look at it and help to resolve this problem. The main part of the code that is problematic is "sht.Calculate".

```
Option Base 1
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Function runCalibrate()
Dim xl As Workbook
Set xl = ThisWorkbook
nRowPerBlock = 15
yrs = Array("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

strikeSentinel = Array(1, 13)
maturitySentinel = Array(1, 10)

nRow = maturitySentinel(2) - maturitySentinel(1) + 1
nCol = strikeSentinel(2) - strikeSentinel(1) + 1
For j = 1 To UBound(yrs)
    Set a = Worksheets(yrs(j)).Cells(3, 2)
    For i = 0 To 11
        b = a.Offset(1 + nRowPerBlock * i, 1).Resize(nRow, nCol)
        xl.Sheets("SPX").Range("p4:ab13") = b

        'refresh required worksheets
        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("TODAY"))
        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("USD"))
        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("SPX"))
        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("EQ Model"))
        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("EQ Calibration"))

        c = xl.Sheets("EQ Calibration").Range("c18:c32")
        xl.Sheets("calibration time series").Cells(38, 2 + 12 * (j - 1) + i).Resize(15, 1) = c
    Next i
Next j

End Function

Function RefreshSheetNX(sht As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    sht.Cells.Dirty
    sht.Calculate
    Call Sleep(1000)
    sht.Calculate
    Call Sleep(1000)
End Function
```

---

As Byron suggested, I use 'Application.CalculateFullRebuild' as in the following code. But it is not reacting at all when I stepped through 'Application.CalculateFullRebuild'.

```
Option Base 1
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Function runCalibrate()
Dim xl As Workbook
Set xl = ThisWorkbook
nRowPerBlock = 15
yrs = Array("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

strikeSentinel = Array(1, 13)
maturitySentinel = Array(1, 10)

nRow = maturitySentinel(2) - maturitySentinel(1) + 1
nCol = strikeSentinel(2) - strikeSentinel(1) + 1
For j = 1 To UBound(yrs)
    Set a = Worksheets(yrs(j)).Cells(3, 2)
    For i = 0 To 11
        b = a.Offset(1 + nRowPerBlock * i, 1).Resize(nRow, nCol)
        xl.Sheets("SPX").Range("p4:ab13") = b

        'refresh required worksheets
'        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("TODAY"))
'        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("USD"))
'        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("SPX"))
'        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("EQ Model"))
'        Call RefreshSheetNX(xl.Sheets("EQ Calibration"))
        Application.CalculateFullRebuild            

        c = xl.Sheets("EQ Calibration").Range("c18:c32")
        xl.Sheets("calibration time series").Cells(38, 2 + 12 * (j - 1) + i).Resize(15, 1) = c
    Next i
Next j

End Function
```

Comment: I don't know if this will make a difference, but in VBA, in general, a `Function` returns a result.  I don't see that either of your functions do that.  You should probably be writing them as `Sub`s.  You also have many undeclared variables in your code.  I suggest adding `Option Explicit` as the first line, which will not only force you to declare all variables, but will also detect typo's and other errors more easily.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `Sleep` function is doing if it is putting the application to sleep. With `Dim dTILL as Double` try `dTILL = Timer + 1: Do While Timer < dTILL: DoEvents: Loop`. Maybe I'm mistaken but I'm pretty sure *nothing* is going to happen while the Excel instance is asleep. Also that sub vs. function thingy.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: I think in VBA, Function subsumes Sub. Function can, but does not have to return a value. Yes, I could also replace Function with Sub, but the current one works. Do you think the declaration would resolve the problem? Like I described in my question, when I step through each line of the VBA code in the debug mode, everything works. Even for the previously stale results, the line by line stepping produces new and expected result. So it does not seem the problem is with the Function/Sub distinction or variable declaration.

Comment: @Jeeped: The Sleep(n) function pause the execution for n miliseconds. Is your code snippet counting time until it reaches a pre-specified count? If so, then it is in effect pausing the code.  Like I described in my question, when I step through each line of the VBA code in the debug mode, everything works (with the Function instead of Sub heading). Even for the previously stale results, the line by line stepping produces new and expected result.

Comment: @Hans In some instances, Functions behave very differently; especially when called from a worksheet, functions often cannot modify another cell.  This is not always the case when called from VBA.  e.g a simple function:  `Function foo() | [a1]="test" | End Function` will fail if called from a worksheet cell; although it works OK in the Immediate Window. And there have been problems with other methods -- more in the past than now.  I generally use functions when I want to return a value, and macros otherwise, but I don't really know if it would make a difference in your code.

Comment: My thoughts on the difference between a `Sub` and `Function` is that it matters only if you want your code to return a value or if you are using the `Function` as a UDF.  If a UDF, you are not allowed to modify anything in the worksheet.  That is, you can only do calculations and return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` instead of multiple calls to `Calculate` for each sheet.  It will force a recalc of everything and rebuild dependencies (as the name implies).

Depending on how formulas are related between sheets, you might not be triggering the right order of calculations processing each sheet one at a time.  The full rebuild approach is the "nuclear option" for refreshing a spreadsheet.  Specifically, calling `sht.Cells.Dirty` and then `sht.Calculate` may only force a refresh of the current sheet without consideration for changes on other sheets.

Comment: Thank you, Byron. I would like to compute the worksheet one at a time so as to make sure it is computed in the right order. I suppose 'Application.CalculateFullRebuild' compute the whole workbook all at once. Is this right? Also, should I remove both 'sht.Cells.Dirty' and 'sht.Calculate', and replace them with one line 'Application.CalculateFullRebuild', or leave the previous two and just add 'Application.CalculateFullRebuild'?  How do you explain the proper execution of the code when I stepped through it line by line in the debug mode?

Comment: I would replace all your calculation code with a single call to `CalculateFullRebuild`.

Comment: OK. Does 'Worksheets(name).CalculateFullRebuild' work?

Comment: No.  It is a Sub that belongs to the `Application` only.

Comment: Byron, I appended the new code to my question. It does not seem to be working. Did I edit the code correctly?

Comment: Looks correct.  What do you mean, "it's not reacting at all"?

Comment: When I step through that line, it just went through without complaints or computing anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77426/discussion-between-hans-and-byron).